# Content in website does not show under the right website name

Tags: nodes

I have created the contents,

And I want the content should be display like www.kvamsdanl.no.

But It was displaying like www.kvamsdanl.no/node/3(or with one of these numbers 1 , 2 or 5).

How do I achieve this thing ?

Please anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have removed the default front page settings. Please head over to /admin/config/system/site-information and add node/3 as default front page. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to add node/3 but had to put /node/3 - and tried both in 403 access denied and 404 site not found - it was what you ment? Unfortunately it was no help. When I go to Kvamsdahl.no I just get the front page where I have to log in, and not the web site. I find the web site with the right information as i add /node/1 and so on. Any suggestions? Very grateful for help!!!